# Rendering some items side by side in extjs4.1.0

Tags: extjs4.1

Iam using extjs4.1.0

I want to have some items in the form panel side by side.

I have tried this having my necessary items in a component with a column layout.

Is there any other way to render some of the items in the form panel side by side without

using the component or container.

Comment: Have you tried Hbox layout? Same as in [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.1.0-gpl/examples/form/hbox-form.html).

Answer (score 0):

No, the Ext.form.Panel uses the form layout by default.  When you specify a different layout, then you will not have fieldLabels displayed correctly.  You have to use containers to make the layout still have fieldLabels using the form layout.  It is not reasonably possible to do what you want here.